# 1mm 8pin ribbon cable connector for breadboards

Tags: cable, connectors

I bought this air quality sensor for my Raspberry PI

[image]
[image]
[image]

As you can see, it uses a small male-male ribbon connector (10mm). I am looking for a clip breadboard connector/adapter as I would like to avoid soldering.
The wires are very small (1mm each).

Are such connectors/adapters available (UK if possible)?
What do you recommend to do if I can't find one?

Comment: It's hard to tell from the picture but that looks like a JST cable end. So what you need is a JST header like this http://www.ebay.com/itm/50sets-JST-Straight-PH-2-0-6-Pin-6P-Connector-Pin-Header-Housing-Terminal-/252581268879?hash=item3acf044d8f:g:0rsAAOSwCGVX~d9P with thecorrect number of pins. Be careful because JST connectors have multiple sizes and spacings. I suggest you get a better pic of the connector and measure the distance between pins (very accurately) then search by the number of pins you need.

Comment: Is the second image better?

Comment: Can you post one of the other side of the connector?

Comment: Done. I have edited my post. It is a male-male cable.

Comment: I ended up buying [this](http://www.hobbytronics.co.uk/ribbon-connector-breadboard-2-5)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am almost certain that is a JST connector, eBay or a local electronics store should have what you need. A cheaper and easier solution would be to use male to male jumper wires to connect it to a breadboard.